# using folder navigation with an RSS feed

Tags: xml, redirect, iis, rss

I have an XML file located within an `rss` folder on my server.  How would I set it up to where all I have to give out is `www.example.com/rss` instead of giving out the full file location `www.example.com/rss/feed.xml`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What kind of web server or hosting solution are you using?

Comment: Hostek - Shared windows server